# How to apply different functions for different columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with shipments:

| booking_order | driver_name | tonnage | stop_name | parcels | kgs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2794 | John | 3 | Warsaw | 200 | 180 |
| 2794 | John | 3 | Radom | 300 | 270 |
| 2794 | John | 3 | Krakow | 150 | 135 |
| 3005 | Mark | 5 | Gdansk | 500 | 450 |
| 3005 | Frank | 5 | Gdynia | 400 | 360 |
| 3005 | Frank | 5 | Sopot | 123 | 10.7 |

Task is to group all rows by booking order and to show for driver name, tonnage and stop_name as unique values inside (set with different delimiters) and sum for parcels and kgs.

Needed result is below:

| booking_order | driver_name | tonnage | stop_name | parcels | kgs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2794 | John | 3 | Warsaw>Radom>Krakow | 650 | 585 |
| 3005 | Mark, Frank | 5 | Gdansk>Gdynia>Sopot | 1023 | 920.7 |

I only could do grouping, but don't know how to apply different methods to different columns correctly

```
import pandas as pd
excel=pd.read_excel('source.xlsx')
result=excel.groupby('booking_order').agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
result.to_excel('result1.xlsx')
```

Comment: From top of my head try this: df.groupby(['booking_order', 'driver_name', 'tonnage'], as_index = False).agg({'stop_name': '>'.join, 'parcels':sum, 'kgs':sum}). Didn't test, because you didn't provide code to reproduce your df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `agg` with a dict of aggregation functions:

```
aggfunc = {'driver_name': lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()),
           'tonnage': 'first',
           'stop_name': '>'.join,
           'parcels': 'sum',
           'kgs': 'sum'}
result = excel.groupby('booking_order', as_index=False).agg(aggfunc)
```

Output:

```
>>> result
   booking_order driver_name  tonnage            stop_name  parcels    kgs
0           2794        John        3  Warsaw>Radom>Krakow      650  585.0
1           3005  Mark,Frank        5  Gdansk>Gdynia>Sopot     1023  820.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
result=(excel.groupby(['booking_order'], as_index=False)
             .agg(driver_name=('driver_name',lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())),
                  tonnage=('tonnage','first'),
                  stop_name=('stop_name','>'.join),
                  parcels=('parcels','sum'),
                  kgs=('kgs','sum')))
print (result)
   booking_order driver_name  tonnage            stop_name  parcels    kgs
0           2794        John        3  Warsaw>Radom>Krakow      650  585.0
1           3005  Mark,Frank        5  Gdansk>Gdynia>Sopot     1023  820.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your aggregations separately.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "a", "b"], "B": [1,2,3,4], "C": [5,6,7,8]})

group_obj = df.groupby("A")

grouper_b = group_obj.B.mean()
grouper_c = group_obj.C.max()

result = pd.concat([grouper_b, grouper_a], axis=1)
```

Or pass the options in `func` to `agg`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

```py
df.groupby("A").agg({"B": min, "C": max})
```